# Magento 2 - adding custom.phtml file

Tags: magento2, product, template

I'm trying to add a custom phtml file in the Product Page before Product Name/Title.

For that I've created a `custom.phtml` file in the path-

> "...> Magento_Catalog > templates > custom.phtml".

After that I added a block in catalog_product_view.xml:

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="blockname" template="Magento_Catalog::custom.phtml"/>
```

What I'm missing here? please guide me to show my custom.phtml file content on product page before the product title.

Comment: What are the contents of custom.phtml file?

Comment: Currently its just simple HTML <h1> tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed something in your layout file (like wrong reference container etc.), which is hard to guess without seeing the code.

Please try below code in your file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="blockname" template="Magento_Catalog::custom.phtml" before="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Refresh the cache after making the modifications.

I have checked the code in my localhost and found it working fine.

Comment: Is my custom.phtml file's path correct?

Comment: Yes, the file path is fine. The problem which I could guess is the wrong container.

Comment: Here's my code <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="blockname" template="Magento_Catalog::category-name.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>

Comment: now getting this error: 
Magento_Catalog/templates/category-name.phtml): failed to open stream: Permission denied in

Comment: The code seems correct. Do you have correct file permissions?

Comment: Your phtml file path should be like: **`app/design/frontend/<ThemePackageName>/<themeaname>/Magento_Catalog/templates/category-name.phtml`**, and should have correct file permissions.

Comment: the path is exactly the same.
For permissions, I guess Yes, because my other custom phtml files working fine in Magento_Theme